# How to understand fourier transform with linear algebra perspective

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I try to understand the Fourier transform using linear algebra, but something goes wrong

Below is my attempt:

Fourier transform is a process try to orthogonal project the input signal $x(t)$ to infinite many basis (like $e^{jwt}$), but what is the inner product defined here? the coefficient for each basis can be proven to be $\langle x(t),e^{jwt}\rangle$ divided by $\langle e^{jwt},e^{jwt}\rangle$ , where $\langle f(t),g(t)\rangle$ denoted as inner product of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$

Comment: The problem is that $e^{j\omega t}$ is not in the underlying vector space of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. So you can't treat the Fourier transform expansion as an inner product expansion in basis elements $e^{j\omega t}$.

Comment: I usually like to think of the Fourier Transform as a simple correlation, where for each specific value of $\omega$ the transform $X(\omega)$ gives you the correlation of $x(t)$ with $e^{-i\omega t}$. But I'm not a mathematician so this approach may be too simplified.